# Sharepoint Color code a cell change

Tags: sharepoint-designer, modified

I am trying to color code the cell that has been changed on a week basis. Lets say on a list on the SharePoint I open the list as **"edit on datasheet"** then I click on **save**. So from today to a week from now, that changes I modified on that list will be colored as red, once the week time-frame passes this color will return to black. Is there a webpart or any type of modification so I can perform this?

Comment: you want change the color on the basis of item created? because using today in calculate formula is not allowed?

Comment: here are formula for the color coding but your date requirement is required extra effort. http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/apply-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-lists/